# ListView не загружает элементы массива

Tags: android, xml, строки, listview

Сделал ListView

```
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_options"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/options"
    />
```

в качестве значений он берёт элементы массива string-array options из файла string.xml

```
<string-array name="options">
    <item>Drinks</item>
    <item>Food</item>
    <item>Stores</item>
</string-array>
```

Но почему то получается вот такая вещь[image]

Значения не применяются. Вроде всё сделал как написано в книге, но что то не выходит

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы хотите видеть свои строки в визуальном редакторе? Это не исполняемый код, а просто картинка, как примерно все будет выглядеть на экране реального устройства. Чтобы увидеть, что у вас получилось на самом деле, вам нужно запустить свою программу на устройстве или в эмуляторе, визуальный редактор не может выполнять код, чтобы вывести динамические значения.

Comment: Некоторой степени кастомизации превью в редакторе вы можете добиться, используя [пространство имен tools](https://android.jlelse.eu/tools-attributes-hidden-gems-of-android-studio-d7451b194e0b), но вывод динамических данных к ним не относится, вы можете использовать атрибуты `tools:listitem` и  `tools:sample` для вывода значений из заранее приготовленного файла JSON (или просто текстового файла с данными, дублирующими данные массива), но такие действия кажутся мне излишними, чтобы просто любоваться на превьюшку. Повторю, у вас на скриншоте - не программа для устройства, а просто превью разметки

Comment: Да, упустил я этот момент. Благодарю за объяснения